# Conditionally add an annotation based on BuildConfig?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, dagger-hilt

I have an android app with multiple build variants. For 1 variant, I need a separate Application that extends AirWatch's application. However, this causes the following error because Hilt requires only a single application to be annotated as the android entry point: `Cannot process multiple app roots in the same compilation unit`. My application classes look like:

```kotlin
@HiltAndroidApp
open class MainApplication() : Application() { }

@HiltAndroidApp
open class MainAWApplication() : Application(), AWSDKApplication by AWSDKApplicationDelegate() { }
```

Is there a way to use a `BuildConfig` value to conditionally apply an annotation?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Android expert but I would recommend a factory pattern for conditional injection of Component classes

[Dagger: how to instantiate different ObjectGraphs depending on the build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765065/dagger-how-to-instantiate-different-objectgraphs-depending-on-the-build)

[Looking for an example for Dagger assisted injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22799407/looking-for-an-example-for-dagger-assisted-injection/22801097#22801097)